# ruby selenium-webdriver wait for element "ensure" does not work

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Trying to wait for element2 to appear on the web page after clicking on element1 using "begin ..ensure" method. If element2 is not there I want to quit and log an error. But element2 appears in couple seconds but the following code goes to ensure block and makes driver quit.
Don't know what is the problem. Thanks in advance:

```
$driver.find_element(:id, "element1").click
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
begin
  wait.until {$driver.find_element(:id, "element2")}
ensure
  #Logger login error to text error log file
  $driver.quit #---------------------------> always goes to ensure and quits
end   
$driver.find_element(:id, "element2").click -->> never gets here
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `find_element` raises a `NoShuchElementException` when an element can't be found (see [doc](http://oc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Find)). The `begin ... ensure ... end` block does not stop the exception, it only execute the code in the `ensure` block before the exception is propagated further. So the code after the end is never reached.

Anyway, I don't understand why you want to call `$driver.quit` and next `$driver.find_element(...)`. Also the `wait` seems useless, you can use the timeout managed by `driver` (see [Implicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp))

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `rescue` instead of `ensure`.

- `ensure` is always run.
- `rescue` is only run when an exception occurs (ie only quit if the element is not found)

Try:

```
begin
  wait.until {$driver.find_element(:id, "element2")}
rescue
  #Logger login error to text error log file
  $driver.quit #---------------------------> always goes to ensure and quits
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the best way to ensure what element exists on the web page before executing next statment

Comment: Selenium-webdriver has built in methods for waiting. Take a look at the explicit and implicit waits - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp